# html ignore extra end tags if existing

Tags: html

we have code that looks something like this

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div>
 ....  function that get some text including html from database.
</div>
</td>
</tr>
<div> ... div that should be in table..</div>
</table>
```

Now my problem is that if the text we get in is for example  "test <//table>"
This will of course end the table prematurely and the last div will end up outside of table.
Is there some trick here without having to count the table tags in the text to prevent this maybe?
Like a forced container around the div where you enter the text preventing it from ending outside tags?
Or some other way?

Trying to clearify then.
THe text in the first div we get from database.
If this text we get in there is incorrect html like just "<//table>"
then I want that html tag to just be ignored and not to end the surrounding table.
But I do want to show the text as html if it is.
So basically I just want the text inside that div to not be able to end tags outside of the div.

Oh I see now, my html tags were removed.

Comment: not clear what you want

Comment: please provide [mcve]

Comment: I think you should approach this a bit differently and parse data antered to database (e.g. auto-close and validate HTML tags)

Comment: If this is user-provided HTML that you are displaying on a page, throw it in an [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) with the `sandbox` attribute and you should be set.

Comment: You should probably use something like HTMLPurifier then to _make_ your content from the database into proper "finished" HTML, when necessary.

Comment: You should filter all HTML from the database values before sending it to the client. When you need simple formating you can use markdown or something like good old BB codes. When you have a complex markup, you should separate it from the actual contents.

Answer (score 0):

you could use something that can check html getting from db is valid or not like [DomParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).if it is valid  you can show the html else return only the text from function .